# regex - how to capture pattern without different pattern before it?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse out prices but ignore two patterns that are also prices. One of the exclusions is the total price which is at the end which I am using lookahead to ignore. The second exclusion is if there's a variation of the letter `Q` before a price, for example `Q10.00` or `Q AWSMSN11.32` but I want to **include** if there's a three letter alpha that happens to end in `Q` such as `YMQ234.03`.

I've added a negative lookbehind but can't seem to get what I want.

This is the pattern I've tried: `(?<![Q\d]) ?M?(\d+\.\d{2})(?=.*\d+\.\d{2}END)`

test strings

```
ABC WS YMQ234.03WS TOY234.03USD468.06END
FUR BB LAB Q10.00 199.00USD209.00END
YAS DG TYY Q AWSMSN11.32 2503.08LD VET Q JKLOLE11.32 2503.08USD5028.80END
PPP VP LAP Q10.00 M342.41EE SFD Q10.00 282.24USD644.65END
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mPcC7H/3)

Expected output

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+
| ABC WS YMQ234.03WS TOY234.03USD468.06END                                  | 234.03  | 234.03  |
| FUR BB LAB Q10.00 199.00USD209.00END                                      | 199.00  |         |
| YAS DG TYY Q AWSMSN11.32 2503.08LD VET Q JKLOLE11.32 2503.08USD5028.80END | 2503.08 | 2503.08 |
| PPP VP LAP Q10.00 M342.41EE SFD Q10.00 282.24USD644.65END                 | 342.41  | 282.24  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might also match what you don't want, and capture what you do want.

Match optional whitespace and uppercase chars where there is a `Q` and match the decimal value that follows.

Make the exception of eliminating this match asserting that it is not preceded by 2 times an uppercase A-Z followed by `Q`

After the alternation, capture the decimal value in group 1, asserting that it is not followed by `END`

```
\b[A-Z ]*Q[A-Z ]*(?<![A-Z][A-Z]Q)\d+\.\d+|(\d+\.\d{2})(?!END)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b[A-Z ]*Q[A-Z ]*` Word boundary, match a `Q` between optional spaces and uppercase chars
- `(?<![A-Z][A-Z]Q)` Negative lookbehind, assert not 2 uppercase chars A-Z followed by `Q` directly to the left
- `\d+\.\d+` Match a decimal value
- `|` Or
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+\.\d{2}` Match 1+ digits followed by a dot and 2 digits
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?!END)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not `END`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yXZ2Le/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/PG4UQa)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"\b[A-Z ]*Q[A-Z ]*(?<![A-Z][A-Z]Q)\d+\.\d+|(\d+\.\d{2})(?!END)"
strings = [
    "ABC WS YMQ234.03WS TOY234.03USD468.06END",
    "FUR BB LAB Q10.00 199.00USD209.00END",
    "YAS DG TYY Q AWSMSN11.32 2503.08LD VET Q JKLOLE11.32 2503.08USD5028.80END",
    "PPP VP LAP Q10.00 M342.41EE SFD Q10.00 282.24USD644.65END"
]

for str in strings:
    print('{}: {}'.format(str, [x.group(1) for x in re.finditer(regex, str) if x.group(1)]))
```

Output

```
ABC WS YMQ234.03WS TOY234.03USD468.06END: ['234.03', '234.03']
FUR BB LAB Q10.00 199.00USD209.00END: ['199.00']
YAS DG TYY Q AWSMSN11.32 2503.08LD VET Q JKLOLE11.32 2503.08USD5028.80END: ['2503.08', '2503.08']
PPP VP LAP Q10.00 M342.41EE SFD Q10.00 282.24USD644.65END: ['342.41', '282.24']
```

Comment: Very nice thought of the capture group.

Comment: I think this was the best overall answer that made the most sense to me, thank you!

Comment: Lovely answer! One detail (resulting in a simplification) that I thought was quite nice was `(?!END)`.

Comment: @The fourth bird is there a way to do two negative lookbehinds as an OR, for example this string `ABC SQ SIN SQ BMO Q ABCBMO250.00 3893.50SQ SIN SQ KLU615.49 KHG SQ SIN1991.31 SQ XLS2535.00USD9285.30END` I'd like to capture the 615.49, 1991.31, and 2535.00 as well in the same group

Comment: nobody, no `Q` in that string is immediately preceded by two letters, yet `615.49`, `1991.31` and `2535.00` are all preceded by a `Q`. What is the rationale for matching those numbers? Perhaps it has to do with "OR", which is not clear.

Comment: @nobody If it should start with an Q, you could add a word boundary `\b[A-Z ]*\bQ[A-Z ]*(?<![A-Z][A-Z]Q)\d+\.\d+|(\d+\.\d{2})(?!END)` https://regex101.com/r/lfwprl/1/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for following up. Yes, if it begins with Q I ignore but there can be other Qs in text that we don't want to

Answer (score 2):

By matching the following regular expression the values of interest will be saved to capture group 1.

```
r'(?=[^Q\d]*(?=\d))(?:(?<!Q)|(?<=[A-Z]{2}Q)|\D*\d+\.\d{2})[^Q\d]*([1-9]\d*\.\d{2})(?!END\b)'
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/mPcC7H/10) | [Python code](http://tpcg.io/XpIrtT1u)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?=               : begin positive lookahead
  [^Q\d]*         : match 0+ chars other that 'Q' and digits
  (?=\d)          : positive lookahead asserts next char is a digit
)                 : end positive lookahead
(?:               : begin non-capture group
  (?<!Q)          : negative lookbehind asserts current match did
                    not end with 'Q'
|                 : or
  (?<=            : begin positive lookbehind
    [A-Z]{2}Q     : match two letters, 'Q'
  )               : end positive lookbehind
|                 : or
  \D*\d+\.\d{2}   : match 0+ non-digits, 1+ digits, '.', 2 digits
)                 : end non-capture group
[^Q\d]*           : match 0+ chars other than 'Q' or digits
([1-9]\d*\.\d{2}) : match digit other than zero, 0+ digits, '.',
                    2 digits
(?!END\b)         : negative lookahead asserts current match is
                  : not followed by 'END'
```

The positive lookahead `(?=[^Q\d]*(?=\d))` leaves the regex engine's internal string pointer at its current location if 'Q' does not appear between the current location and the first digit of a string that matches `[1-9]\d*\.\d{2}`. Otherwise it moves the pointer to just after the last 'Q' that precedes the first digit of a string that matches `[1-9]\d*\.\d{2}`.

Comment: This returns the 11.32 prices also which I would like to exclude

Comment: Also I should've mentioned it's not always YMQ, it's any three alpha characters that end in Q

Comment: nobody, it took awhile, but I believe my revision meets requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `regex` module instead of `re` with the pattern:

```
Q[A-Z ]*(?<!\b[A-Z]{2}Q)[\d.]+(*SKIP)(*F)|\d+(?:\.\d+)(?!\d*END$)
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/w0kyNL/5).

---

In Python this could look like:

```
import regex
arr = ['ABC WS YMQ234.03WS TOY234.03USD468.06END', 'FUR BB LAB Q10.00 199.00USD209.00END', 'YAS DG TYY Q AWSMSN11.32 2503.08LD VET Q JKLOLE11.32 2503.08USD5028.80END', 'PPP VP LAP Q10.00 M342.41EE SFD Q10.00 282.24USD644.65END']
res = [regex.findall(r'Q[A-Z ]*(?<!\b[A-Z]{2}Q)[\d.]+(*SKIP)(*F)|\d+(?:\.\d+)(?!\d*END$)',x) for x in arr]
print(res)
```

Prints:

```
[['234.03', '234.03'], ['199.00'], ['2503.08', '2503.08'], ['342.41', '282.24']]
```

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland. I'll go with `findall` for now. While Python is not my forte (and you may be right) I see two columns of results in the OP. Not sure it's just about the *first* match alone.

Comment: Yes I was looking for both prices. Unfortunately I cannot use regex module, only re

Answer (score 1):

You may use a simple well-known trick when you need to discard some matches: use an optional capturing group that will only match when a failure is expected:

```
(\bQ\s?[A-Z]*)?(?<!\d)(\d+\.\d{2})(?=.*\d\.\d{2}END)
|_____________|
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IBRG3w/1). Whenever match data object Group 1 is not empty, the match should be dropped.

**Regex details**

- `(\bQ\s?[A-Z]*)?` - an optional capturing group #1 that captures

  - `\bQ` - a word boundary followed with `Q`
  - `\s?` - one or zero whitespaces
  - `[A-Z]*` - any 0 or more ASCII uppercase letters
- `(?<!\d)` - no digit immediately on the left is allowed
- `(\d+\.\d{2})` - 1+ digits, `.` and then any two digits
- `(?=.*\d\.\d{2}END)` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible followed with a digit, `.`, two digits and `END` must appear immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [Python implementation](https://ideone.com/TlWBQP) with `re`:

```
import re
strings = ['ABC WS YMQ234.03WS TOY234.03USD468.06END','FUR BB LAB Q10.00 199.00USD209.00END','YAS DG TYY Q AWSMSN11.32 2503.08LD VET Q JKLOLE11.32 2503.08USD5028.80END','PPP VP LAP Q10.00 M342.41EE SFD Q10.00 282.24USD644.65END']
rx = r'(\bQ\s?[A-Z]*)?(?<!\d)(\d+\.\d{2})(?=.*\d\.\d{2}END)'
for s in strings:
    matches = [x.group(2) for x in re.finditer(rx, s) if not x.group(1)] # note the if condition that drops unwlecome matches
    print(s, matches, sep=" => ")
```

Output:

```
ABC WS YMQ234.03WS TOY234.03USD468.06END => ['234.03', '234.03']
FUR BB LAB Q10.00 199.00USD209.00END => ['199.00']
YAS DG TYY Q AWSMSN11.32 2503.08LD VET Q JKLOLE11.32 2503.08USD5028.80END => ['2503.08', '2503.08']
PPP VP LAP Q10.00 M342.41EE SFD Q10.00 282.24USD644.65END => ['342.41', '282.24']
```

Comment: If I understand the requirements correctly there may be a small problem: if the first `'Y'` is removed in the first example, `ABC WS MQ234.02WS TOY234.03USD468.06END #=> ['234.02', '234.03']` (where I've changed the first number slightly for greater clarity), whereas I believe it should be `#=> ['234.03']`. If so, I believe there's an easy fix by replacing `\bQ` with `(?<!\b[A-Z]{2})Q`.